# simple Controller not working with Magento2

Tags: magento2, controllers

Trying to follow this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/ to create a module, but nothing is working for me.
I am using Magento with xampp.

My root folder name is Magento2

path: `C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\app\code\Mageplaza`

created: **HelloWorld** folder

> C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld

- **Controller** folder
- **etc** folder
- registration.php

**registration.php**

```
<?php 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mageplaza_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

Inside etc folder:

- **frontend** folder

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" setup_version="2.0.0" />
</config>
```

Inside frontend folder

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="mageplaza" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Inside Controller folder:

- **Index** folder

Inside Index folder:

**Display.php**

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
  {
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function execute()
  {
    echo 'Hello World';
    exit;
  }
}
```

url: http://localhost/Magento2/helloworld/index/display
result: 404

Any idea where I am going wrong, just started learning magneto2.

Comment: Did you run php  bin/magento  setup:upgrade check you module in the list as well as cache:clean.

Comment: i check this code there is not problem in that i think you missed the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` of install the module

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it fixes the issue after running the following command.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 1):

One other thing, make sure you've enabled your module.

`bin/magento module:enable MyModule_Module
 bin/magenot setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Please Check with your Vendorname and the Modulename whether it is mentioned properly.Because I had the same issue due to misspelled modulename. But there is no issue on your coding.

Answer (score 0):

When Create custom module than first u run command 
Below step by step

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush

Than run in url baseurl/helloworld/index/display

Comment: You don't need to call `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` in developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the reindex command.

follow these steps

1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
2. php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Note: --keep-generated argument is passed to keep generated static data. Otherwise you have to run setup:static-content:deploy command to regenerate all the static data.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

This may be quite late response. Anyway hope this helps someone else to solve the issue.

In your **routes.xml** change the below line to have the same value as **id** and **frontname**

> Before :
>
> ```
> <route id="mageplaza" frontName="helloworld">
> ```
>
> After :
>
> ```
> <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
> ```

**Clear cache** and try again loading the page

**NOTE :** If you have different values for route **id** and **frontname** the routing will not work properly. Of course it would redirect you up to the controller function (if you echo something and exit from the controller the page would show the echoed wordings), but it would not load the relevant Block there. Obviously, the phtml file will not load.

Answer (score 0):

Check `\Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList::get` (by setting a breakpoint) whether your controller class is actually instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface` - typos in `namespace` and `use` statements can prevent that - and it silently falls back to 404

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you created the files in wrong directories.

You module.xml is in **frontend** folder but it should be in **etc** folder.

Answer (score 0):

Also, please ensure that your controller is inside **Controller/<action>/** directory, not inside Controller folder alone.